# How can I create a function that alternates how much it adds each time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to find a function that can accomplish the goal as stated in the title.
For example:

f(1)=50

f(2)=150

f(3)=200

f(4)=300

f(5)=350

f(6)=450

and so on. I've been working on this for a hot minute and am struggling. I tried for a while to get trigonometric functions that would alternate between values of 1 and 0 for adding 50 and 100 alternating, but can't figure out how to use the previous value to add that on top of. I feel that I am missing something fairly obvious and I just need some help / a push in the right direction.

Comment: The difference between $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ is $150$, not $100$ and not $50$. For a heavy duty solution, use [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial?wprov=sfti1#). If you *really* want something that alternates between adding $100$ and adding $50$, look at a summand of the form $75 + (-1)^k25$.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function

```
f(i) = 50*i + 50*FLOOR(i/2)
```

| i | f(i) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 300 |
| 5 | 350 |
| 6 | 450 |
| 7 | 500 |
| 8 | 600 |
| .. | .. |
| i | $50\,i + 50\,{\rm floor}(i/2)$ |